# C# equivalent of OpenSSL signing

Tags: c#, openssl, cryptography, sha256

I have to sign some data using SHA256, and I have an example created with OpenSSL:

```
johnd@johns-machine:~/sandboxcerts$ signingString="(request-target): post /oauth2/token
date: Wed, 11 Apr 2018 15:07:23 GMT
digest: SHA-256=47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=
x-ing-reqid: e86bf09b-d772-4528-af83-ba42aa594ac4"

johnd@johns-machine:~/sandboxcerts$ signature=`printf "$signingString" | openssl dgst -sha256 -sign ~/sandboxcerts/example_client_signing.key -passin "pass:changeit" | openssl base64 -A`
```

I am trying to do the same thing in C# like this:

```
// loading my private key
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath, certPass);
RSACryptoServiceProvider key = cert.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;

string signingString = @"(request-target): post /oauth2/token
date: Wed, 11 Apr 2018 15:07:23 GMT
digest: SHA - 256 = 47DEQpj8HBSa +/ TImW + 5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU =
        x - ing - reqid: e86bf09b - d772 - 4528 - af83 - ba42aa594ac4";

signingString = signingString.Replace("\n", string.Empty);
signingString = signingString.Replace("\r", string.Empty);
signingString = signingString.Replace("\t", string.Empty);

byte[] sig = privKey.SignData(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(signingString), CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"));
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(sig));
```

but I am not getting the same result. I tried different encodings and removing or not removing new lines, tabs etc. but I still didn't get it right.

Comment: Save your input strings to file and compare at a binary level, or load them into a hex editor. Doesn't `SignData` also require a padding mode?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the same signing scheme in both. SHA256 is not a signing scheme. It's just the algorithm to produce your digest to be signed. Based on the OpenSSL CLI wiki (https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Command_Line_Utilities) the signing algorithm is defined by the signing key type (RSA, DSA, etc). If you are using an RSA key, the scheme defaults to pkcs#1 v1.5.

I'm no C# expert so there could be better ways to do PKCS#1 v1.5 signing, but I found **RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter** after quick googling (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsapkcs1signatureformatter?view=netframework-4.7.2). This class seems to work together with **RSACryptoServiceProvider** that you are already using.

The example by Microsoft:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

class RSASample
{

    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            //Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider.
            using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                //The hash to sign.
                byte[] hash;
                using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create())
                {
                    byte[] data = new byte[] { 59, 4, 248, 102, 77, 97, 142, 201, 210, 12, 224, 93, 25, 41, 100, 197, 213, 134, 130, 135 };
                    hash = sha256.ComputeHash(data);
                }

                //Create an RSASignatureFormatter object and pass it the 
                //RSACryptoServiceProvider to transfer the key information.
                RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter RSAFormatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(rsa);

                //Set the hash algorithm to SHA256.
                RSAFormatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256");

                //Create a signature for HashValue and return it.
                byte[] SignedHash = RSAFormatter.CreateSignature(hash);
            }

        }
        catch (CryptographicException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT:** After checking further the C# docs, you could alternatively try to make only a minor change to your current code snippet. The 3rd parameter for `SignData()` is `RSASignaturePadding` and you could try to provide `RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1` for it (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsasignaturepadding?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Basically your 2nd last code line would then look like:

```
byte[] sig = privKey.SignData(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(signingString), CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"), RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
```

Comment: I tried both ways, and got the same result, but different from the one I am supposed to get. :/

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I am trying to do something similar.